# How to get time (hh:mm:ss) from two different dates in java

Tags: java, date

i am getting milleseconds from two different dates, trying to convert milleseconds to timestamp. i have written the following code.

```
    Date d1 = new Date();
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    Date d2 = new Date();
    System.out.println(d1);
    System.out.println(d2);

    long seconds = d2.getTime()-d1.getTime();
    Date d3 = new Date(seconds);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(seconds);
    System.out.println("Time is : "+df.format(d3));

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(seconds);
    System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

the for loop would take 2 or 3 seconds, the result may be 00:03:80, but my result always getting

```
Time is : 05:30:04
05:30:04
```

but actual difference is 2 or 3 second, is this correct way or is there any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the time zone:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(seconds);
System.out.println("Time is : "+df.format(d3));
```

The `Date` class measures time as milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. It looks like your local time is 5 hours ahead of UTC - or was on January 1 1970 - making the UTC "zero" date occur at 5 AM in your timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a *for loop* do

```
Thread.sleep(2000); // 2000 milliseconds
```

And the rest should work. It happens so that Java compiler optimizes, remove or rearrange the code so you are not utterly sure if the instantiation of `d1` happened before or after the loop. It could be anything.